# Custom user control - dynamic image binding depends on property value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, dependencies

I am trying to make a button with icon, where icon will change depends on property.
This is what I have now:

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="TestButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="5">
                    <StackPanel Background="DodgerBlue">
                        <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

Code behind a button:

```
public partial class TestButton : UserControl
{
    [Flags]
    public enum ButtonType
    {
        Regular,
        Close
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonType", typeof(ButtonType), typeof(TestButton), new PropertyMetadata(ButtonType.Regular, new PropertyChangedCallback(Test)));

    private static void Test(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        ButtonType type = (ButtonType)e.NewValue;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (type == ButtonType.Alert)
        {
            bitmap = Properties.Resources.appbar_close;
        }

        Icon = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, new Int32Rect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }

    public ButtonType Type
    {
        get { return (ButtonType)GetValue(ButtonTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    public TestButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static ImageSource _icon;
    public static ImageSource Icon
    {
        set => _icon = value;
    }


}
```

I want to use my button like:

```
<ctrl:TestButton Type="Close" />
```

But I don't know what should I do with image's source property. What should I bind?

I have to say that buttons style is in another file.

Is this correct way?

Comment: The easiest way would be to make a new style for each type in a resource dictionary. Then when making the button use the style key: `Style="CloseButtonStyle"`

Comment: Yes, that is one option, but what if there will be 100 types of button? I want to avoid copy&paste unnecessary code and replace it by i.e switch/case in 'Test' callback function

Comment: I would then make different editable properties, for example the only difference between a close button and a minimize button is the buttons content being a different character.